# Running a query and displaying result it in a TEdit

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-xe3

I have a `TComboBox` containing a list of names gathered from my database. Next to it is a `TEdit` that I intend on using for the purposes for displaying the ID number associated to each person.

Since firstName and lastName are separate fields within the table, but displayed together in the TCombobox I have written a small section to split the firstName and lastName into two separate variables:

> ```
>  pos := AnsiPos(' ', cbStudents.Text); 
>  firstName := Copy(cbStudents.Text, 0, pos-1);
>  lastName := Copy(cbStudents.Text, pos+1, Length(cbStudents.Text));
> ```

Then I execute the SQL code:

```
  try
    query.Open;
    query.SQL.Add('Select studentID');
    query.SQL.Add('From student');
    query.SQL.Add('Where firstName = ' + StrToQuote(firstName));
    query.SQL.Add('And lastName = ' + StrToQuote(lastName));
    editID.Text := query
  finally
    query.Free;
  end;
```

Note: `StrToQuote` encapsulates the variable firstName and lastName with double quotes (" ")

The error that I am receiving is:

Argument out of range

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advanced for the help.

Comment: Use parameters. Your current approach is open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: This approach depends on hope - i hope i will never get Students with the same name or students with more than one firstname. So you become a prayer and not a programmer. It is always a good advice not to interpret the visualized data, because it has already been interpreted for visualization needs. So the result will depend on dependings. Just in case use facts and store the corresponding StudentID in a lookup list to retrieve it with the ItemIndex of your ComboBox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code can not work. It opens the query first, then it sets the SQL query string. Instead of

```
   try
     query.Open;
     query.SQL.Add('Select studentID');
     query.SQL.Add('From student');
     query.SQL.Add('Where firstName = ' + StrToQuote(firstName));
     query.SQL.Add('And lastName = ' + StrToQuote(lastName));
   finally
     query.Free;
   end;
```

use

```
  // create or reset query here
  query := ...

  try

    query.SQL.Add('SELECT studentID');
    query.SQL.Add('FROM student');
    query.SQL.Add('WHERE firstName = :firstname');
    query.SQL.Add('AND lastName = :lastName');

    // set parameter values here

    query.Open;

    // now transfer data from fields to the user interface (TEdit)

  finally
    query.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: How do I go about using the parameters?

Answer (score 3):

Your approach does not seam optimal for me (splitting Displayed Name), but your problem here would be accessing query.Fields[0].AsString after freeing the query.

Comment: Other than the fact that it is open to SQL attacks, why would my approach not be optimal?

Comment: Names could also contain more part Klaus Dieter von der Leinen. In your case you would be able to use a DBlookupcombobox with direkt access to all Information you need. You also could add a ID to Items.Objekts or dirket reference to on reading created Objects.

Comment: That's a good point +1, but I will have boundaries for the purpose of this project.